# Change background colour on typing certain value (jNumberField)

Tags: java

I am trying to change the background colour of a number field based on the numbers that are typed in. Just like a number field turns red when you type a letter in it. I want it to also change red when you type numbers below 1 and above 7.
I understand that you can do this with a button, but I want it to change when you're typing.

This is my code:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
public class applet03 extends JApplet {
  private JButton bHoeveelheid = new JButton();
  private JNumberField nfAantal = new JNumberField();  
  private JTextArea taLijst = new JTextArea("");
    private JScrollPane taLijstScrollPane = new JScrollPane(taLijst);
 public void init() {
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(null);
    cp.setBounds(0, 0, 442, 478);
    bHoeveelheid.setBounds(224, 56, 59, 33);
    bHoeveelheid.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
    bHoeveelheid.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        bHoeveelheid_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    cp.add(bHoeveelheid);
    nfAantal.setBounds(304, 56, 99, 36);
    nfAantal.setText("Vul getal in");
    nfAantal.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    nfAantal.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() { 
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt) { 
        nfAantal_FocusGained(evt);
      }
    });
    nfAantal.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { 
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) { 
        nfAantal_KeyPressed(evt);
      }
    });
    cp.add(nfAantal);
    taLijstScrollPane.setBounds(224, 136, 168, 180);
    cp.add(taLijstScrollPane);
  }
  public void bHoeveelheid_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {    
    if (nfAantal.getInt() < 1 || nfAantal.getInt() > 7) {
      nfAantal.setBackground(Color.RED);
    } else {
      //some other code (not impotant for now)
      }
  }  
  public void nfAantal_FocusGained(FocusEvent evt) {    
    if (nfAantal.getText().equals("Vul getal in")) {
      nfAantal.clear();
    }
  }  
  public void nfAantal_KeyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    if (nfAantal.getInt() < 1 || nfAantal.getInt() > 7) {
      nfAantal.setBackground(Color.RED);
    } else {
      //some other code (not impotant for now)
      }
  }  
}
```

The button part works, but the KeyEvent not.
And when I run this I keep getting these errors:

```java
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

But when I do this, it kinda works. I still get the same errors but it works. (By the way not optimal, because it only appends it to the text field every second key pressing.):

```java
  public void nfAantal_KeyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    if (nfAantal.getInt() < 1 || nfAantal.getInt() > 7) {
      taLijst.append(nfAantal.getText());
    } else {
      //some other code (not impotant for now)
      }
  }
```

So if someone knows why this doesn't work or knows a better way to accomplish this. Then that would be very appreciated!

(By the way I use Java 1.8)

**Edit:**

I now have `(nfAantal.getText().length() > 0) && (nfAantal.getInt() < 1 || nfAantal.getInt() > 7)` in the if statement and that got rid of the errors. (Thanks to @Joe)
But that still doesn't solve my question on how to turn the background red on certain values.

**Aditional information about `JNumberField`:**

I think [this link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jAKgs_ErC-gJ:www.javaeditor.org/wiki/jedownload/JNumberField.java) has the code that makes up `JNumberField` and [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hoWjI0A-KEnwakZFNxzR0XiWxdeaanmp/view?usp=sharing) contains a download to the .jar file with in there the `JNumberField` Java file.

**Another edit:**

I think I found out for myself why it doesn't work with a `JNumberfield`; in the code it changes the background to white if its value is numeric so only if there is a way to get around this part of the code or change it (which I don't know how to do) my question can be answered for a `JNumberField`, if this isn't the case then I will use the `JFormattedTextField` instead.

This is the code that needs to be altered or circumvented:

```java
  protected void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    super.processKeyEvent(e);
    if (isNumeric() || getText().equals("-") ||
        getText().equals("") || getText().equals("."))
      setBackground(Color.white);
    else
      setBackground(Color.red);
  }
```

Comment: the nfAantal.getText() works because it always returns something: a string with the length from 0 to infinite. But the nfAantal.setBackground(Color.RED) runs into troubles if the text field has the length 0 and that is the exception you got: empty String. Solution: check the length before set the background color.

Comment: @Joe If I add `String.valueOf(nfAantal.getInt()).length() != 0` to the if statement I still get the same error.

Comment: It should be: if (nfAantal.getText().length() > 0).

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of the errors but the number field background still doesn't turn red :(

Comment: see @Abra's answer. It depends on the implementation of the JNumberField (which is NOT a standard API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what a `JNumberField` is. It's not part of the JDK and when I searched with Google, it turned up several different ones.

I also don't understand why you are writing an *applet*.

Therefore, the below code may not be appropriate since it is a stand-alone *Swing* application that uses [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

public class RedNumbr implements DocumentListener, Runnable {
    private JFormattedTextField  aantal;
    private JFrame  frame;

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
        handleDocumentEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
        handleDocumentEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
        // Never called for 'JFormattedTextField'
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createNumberPanel() {
        JPanel numberPanel = new JPanel();
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
        NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
        aantal = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        aantal.setColumns(10);
        Document doc = aantal.getDocument();
        doc.addDocumentListener(this);
        numberPanel.add(aantal);
        return numberPanel;
    }

    private void handleDocumentEvent(DocumentEvent event) {
        Document doc = event.getDocument();
        int len = doc.getLength();
        if (len > 0) {
            try {
                String text = doc.getText(0, len);
                int number = Integer.parseInt(text);
                Color fg;
                if (number < 1  ||  number > 7) {
                    fg = Color.red;
                }
                else {
                    fg = UIManager.getColor("TextField.foreground");
                }
                aantal.setForeground(fg);
            }
            catch (BadLocationException | NumberFormatException x) {
                // Ignore.
            }
        }
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createNumberPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new RedNumbr());
    }
}
```

Whenever the contents of the `JFormattedTextField` are changed, the relevant `DocumentListener` method is invoked. In those methods I check whether the `JFormattedTextField` contains a number and if it does then I change the foreground color of the `JFormattedTextField` according to your conditions, i.e. if the number is less than one (1) or greater than 7 (seven).

Note that the `NumberFormatter` does not prevent entering non-digits because `JFormattedTextField` handles that when it loses focus. Nonetheless it handles entering positive and negative numbers, which saves you some work. And the point of my answer is simply to demonstrate how to change the foreground color based on the entered text, which I believe answers your question.

### EDIT

In order to change the background of the `JFormattedTextField`, rather than the foreground, you just need to change two lines in my code, above.

Replace

```java
fg = UIManager.getColor("TextField.foreground");
```

with

```java
fg = UIManager.getColor("TextField.background");
```

and also replace

```java
aantal.setForeground(fg);
```

with

```java
aantal.setBackground(fg);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this indeed does answer my question. The only thing is that if I change `setForeground` to `setBackground` it all of a sudden doesn't work any more. I have no idea why.

Comment: Weird, I already tried that, but it didn't work, so I thought I must have done something wrong. But now you said that that was the solution. I tried again and this time also changed the Field back to a `JFormattedTextField` (I changed it to a `JNumberField`) and now it works! But I would not know why using a `JNumberField` would not work. You probably also don't know since you don't heard of an `JNumberField` before.   
But in the case you might want to help me out further, I added my question with additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the JNumberField is an extension of JTextField and if it is the case it could be the synchronization problem between the main thread and the thread that is triggered by the KeyEvent action. To make sure that the event thread will be carried out you code it with invokeLater.

```
  public void nfAantal_KeyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    if (nfAantal.getText().length() > 0) && (nfAantal.getInt() < 1 || nfAantal.getInt() > 7) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
          {
             public void run()
             {
                nfAantal.setBackground(Color.RED);
             }
           });
    } else {
      //some other code (not impotant for now)
      }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. Your code works, but I think I have chosen the wrong event, because now it only turns red when I press a key and then immediately after i realease the key it gets white again. But that could also have something to do with the way `JNumberField` is coded.